# Why is the site blog not link in menu?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

We have a blog at http://aviation.blogoverflow.com/
It is said to be official blog for us.

Why is it not linked to when I click from blog link from the top left hand corner menu?

[image: Blog Link]

Comment: Nice, I saw the chat room about the blog, but I never found out where the blog resided. Got a lot of reading up to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just changed it to link to our blog now. It wasn't before because the SE blog is the default, and for a long time the aviation blog had no content.